# Como puedo utilizar la sentencia switch cuando el usuario tiene que introducir dos variables por pantalla?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer un programa con sentencias `switch` (ya se que es mas fácil con `if`, y ya lo tengo hecho así pero quiero hacerlo con `switch`), en el cual debo meter las variables `dia` y `mes` por pantalla, siendo las dos números enteros.

Me esta dando errores ya que al meter los valores se salta a `default` y no se como hacer que lea los *cases* he intentado poner `if` dentro de los cases pero creo que no he mejorado el problema. Que puedo hacer para que este programa funcione?

He intentado buscar durante todo el día ejemplos de como utilizar dos variables con la sentencia `switch` pero solo encuentro con una variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int dia, mes, signo;

printf("Introduzca el dia {1-31}: ");
scanf("%d", &dia);
printf("Introduzca el mes {1-12}: ");
scanf("%d", &mes);

switch(signo)
{
    case 1: if(mes == 3 && dia >= 21 || mes == 4 && dia <= 19)
        printf("\nAries");
        break;

    case 2: if(mes == 4 && dia >= 20 || mes == 5 && dia <= 20)
        printf("\nTauro");
        break;

    case 3: if(mes == 5 && dia >= 21 || mes == 6 && dia <= 20)
        printf("\nGeminis");
        break;

    case 4: if(mes == 6 && dia >= 21 || mes == 7 && dia <= 21)
        printf("\nCancer");
        break;

    case 5: if(mes == 7 && dia >= 23 || mes == 8 && dia <= 22)
        printf("\nLeo");
        break;

    case 6: if(mes == 8 && dia >= 23 || mes == 9 && dia <= 22)
        printf("\nVirgo");
        break;

    case 7: if(mes == 9 && dia >= 23 || mes == 10 && dia <= 21)
        printf("\nLibra");
        break;

    case 8: if(mes == 10 && dia >= 22 || mes == 11 && dia <= 21)
        printf("\nEscorpio");
        break;

    case 9: if(mes == 11 && dia >= 22 || mes == 12 && dia <= 21)
        printf("\nSagitario");
        break;

    case 10: if(mes == 12 && dia >= 22 || mes == 1 && dia <= 20)
        printf("\nCapricornio");
        break;

    case 11: if(mes == 1 && dia >= 21 || mes == 2 && dia <= 18)
        printf("\nAcuario");
        break;

    case 12: if(mes == 2 && dia >= 19 || mes == 3 && dia <= 20)
        printf("\nPiscis");
        break;

    default: printf("Error al introducir la fecha");

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal es, como ya te han comentado, que la variable `signo` **no está inicializada**.

Ahora bien, antes de usar `switch` tienes que decidir primero cómo debe funcionar (bueno, esto es aplicable a cualquier algoritmo que quieras implementar).

Por ejemplo, `switch` podría usarse para separar los casos en base al mes:

```
switch(mes)
{
    case 1:
      if( dia <= 20 )
        printf("Capricornio");
      else
        printf("Acuario");
      break;

    case 2:
      if( dia <= 18 )
        printf("Acuario");
      else
        printf("Piscis");
      break;

    case 3:
      if( dia <= 20)
        printf("Piscis");
      else
        printf("Aries");
      break;

    case 4:
      if( dia <= 19 )
        printf("Aries");
      else
        printf("Tauro");
      break;

    case 5:
     if( dia <= 20 )
       printf("Tauro");
     else
       printf("Geminis");
     break;

    case 6:
      if( dia <= 20 )
        printf("Geminis");
      else
        printf("Cancer");
      break;

    case 7:
      if( dia <= 21 )
        printf("Cancer");
      else
        printf("Leo");
      break;

    case 8:
      if( dia <= 22 )
        printf("Leo");
      else
        printf("Virgo");
      break;

    case 9:
      if( dia <= 22 )
        printf("Virgo");
      else
        printf("Libra");
      break;

    case 10:
      if( dia <= 21 )
        printf("Libra");
      else
        printf("Escorpio");
      break;

    case 11:
      if( dia <= 21 )
        printf("Escorpio");
      else
        printf("nSagitario");
      break;

    case 12:
      if( dia <= 21 )
        printf("Sagitario");
      else
        printf("Capricornio");
      break;

    default:
      printf("Error al introducir la fecha");
      break;
}
```

Pero claro, el código resultante es un poco redundante ya que tenemos que repetir dos veces cada signo.

Efectivamente, lo más sencillo, en este caso, sería usar `if-else`:

```
if( (mes == 3 && dia >= 21) || (mes == 4 && dia <= 19) )
    printf("\nAries");
else if( mes == 4 || (mes == 5 && dia <= 20) )
    printf("\nTauro");
else if( mes == 5 || (mes == 6 && dia <= 20) )
    printf("\nGeminis");
else if( mes == 6 || (mes == 7 && dia <= 21) )
    printf("\nCancer");
else if( mes == 7 || (mes == 8 && dia <= 22) )
    printf("\nLeo");
else if( mes == 8 || (mes == 9 && dia <= 22) )
    printf("\nVirgo");
else if( mes == 9 || (mes == 10 && dia <= 21) )
    printf("\nLibra");
else if( mes == 10 || (mes == 11 && dia <= 21) )
    printf("\nEscorpio");
else if( mes == 11 || (mes == 12 && dia <= 21) )
    printf("\nSagitario");
else if( mes == 12 || (mes == 1 && dia <= 20) )
    printf("\nCapricornio");
else if( mes == 1 || (mes == 2 && dia <= 18) )
    printf("\nAcuario");
else if( mes == 2 || mes == 3 )
    printf("\nPiscis");
else 
    printf("Error al introducir la fecha");
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu falla es por que utilizas mal switch. La variable *signo* en tu código no esta inicializada con ningún valor, y al entrar al switch, no calza con ningún caso y salta al default.

Para usar switch:

```
switch ( <expresión> )
{
   case <expresión_1> : [ <bloque_de_instrucciones_1> ]
                        [ break; ]
   case <expresión_2> : [ <bloque_de_instrucciones_2> ]
                        [ break; ]
   ...
   case <expresión_n> : [ <bloque_de_instrucciones_n> ]
                        [ break; ]
            [ default : <bloque_de_instrucciones_n+1> ]
}
```

Donde *expresión1,expresión2, ...* se comparan para valores los posibles valores de *expresión*. Para el problema que intentas resolver usar un switch de esa manera no es solución !!
Si lo que buscas es la solución ordenada, puedes crear estructuras de la forma *typedef struct* para cada horóscopo y así limitar los casos, pero si es una tarea sólo puedo dejar esa recomendación, saludos !

Comment: Toda la razon, respuesta editada !